# PDO search form broken link

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I built a form that fetches information it works great but there's a problem I came across, the URL isn't changing at the end. Making it impossible to display a link to that search term only.

Say I searched for the term "Google Search"

My URL is still

```
http://localhost/search.php
```

When I worked with mysql after I've searched a term it would look some what like this

```
http://localhost/search.php?k=google+search
```

What do I change to make this possible?

search engine form:

```
<form name="frmSearch" method="post" action="../search.php">
<input class="inp" name="var1" type="text" id="var1">
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Search engine page:

```
<?php
$nameofdb = 'xxxxxx';
$dbusername = 'xxxxxx';
$dbpassword = 'xxxxxx';


// Connect to MySQL via PDO
try {
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$nameofdb;host=xxxxxx", $dbusername, $dbpassword);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$var1 = $_POST['var1'];


$query = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE title LIKE :search OR keywords LIKE :search";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':search', '%' . $var1 . '%', PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set 
print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n"); */


$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach( $result as $row ) {
   /* echo */ $row["title"];
   /* echo */ $row["keywords"];
  /* echo */  $row["photo"];
  /* echo */  $row["link"];

  echo "<a href=$row[link]> $row[photo] </a>";

}



if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) { 
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach( $result as $row ) {
echo $row["id"];
echo $row["title"];
}
} else {
echo 'There is nothing to show';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the "POST"-method for the request, all form data is added to the HTTP-body.

Try using `method="GET"`

Here a short doc: [HTML form method Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp)

Comment: Sometimes I forget the simplest things, Thanks!

Comment: I changed method="GET" I thought it had worked but now it's showing me all the results with whatever term I search? any advice

Comment: Christmas is coming ^^! Change `$var1 = $_POST['var1'];`to `$var1 = $_GET['var1'];`